# Using async task groups in swift, what's the proper way to skip some items?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, task

I have an app that currently displays list of items to the user. These items are held in an array of a protocol I defined (and one of two classes conforming to it), and is (currently) constructed by some very broken code using GCD by looping through an array of `String` which are used to initialize the different instances of my class.

I'm trying to migrate to using `async`/`await` and task groups.

In my current code, the loop contemplates some checks to skip some of the items in the input, for example:

One of the possible classes I'm using is a representation of an Application bundle. I don't want to have duplicates in my final array, but more than one input string could result in virtually identical instances of my class (chiefly, different versions of an Application that reside at different paths).

So, I currently have a snippet that reads:

```swift
if let wrappedApp = SWDAApplicationItem(item) {
 if (outputItems.first() { ($0 as! SWDAApplicationItem).appBundleInfo?.appBundleID == wrappedApp.appBundleInfo?.appBundleID } == nil) { outputItems.append(wrappedApp) }
}
```

What is the best way to replicate this kind of check when using task groups? I thought about using

```swift
withTaskGroup(of: SWDAAplicationItem?)
```

But even in this case, the compiler frowns at me trying to return `nil` on any given task.

I'm not clear if this is what `TaskGroup.next()` is for, or if instead, maybe I should implement a similar check to what I currently have, but on the `for await` part of the code?

As a final sub-question, what's the proper way to update my UI while the background works on the content; just make the updating function `@MainActor` and call it from within each task?

Comment: I think you need to break your process into two parts. First, you have the asynchronous operations to fetch the bits of information. You are going to perform these tasks anyway, so there is no point in trying to put the check there. Then, once you have all of those results, you want to produce your de-duplicated output array. This is not an asynchronous operation. You can just use a loop to do this.